# Understanding the difference between Posterior Probability versus Likelihood

Tags: probability-theory, decision-theory

I am trying to understand the difference between posterior probability versus likelihood. Here is the source material I'm working off of:

> To say that $H$ has a high likelihood, given observation $O$, is to
>   comment on the value of $Pr(H \mid O)$, not on the value of $Pr(O \mid H)$; the
>   latter is $H$’s posterior probability. It is perfectly possible for a
>   hypothesis to have a high likelihood and a low posterior probability.
>   When you hear noises in your attic, this confers a high likelihood on
>   the hypothesis that there are gremlins up there bowling, but few of us
>   would conclude that this hypothesis is probably true.

My question is, can we understand the likelihood of the gremlins bowling as $Pr(H \mid O)$ where $O$ is the probability of hearing noises given that $H$ occurs (that gremlins are bowling) but that $Pr(O \mid H)$ is extremely unlikely since gremlins don't exist?

Comment: edited question to format formulas, i'm not sure if any typo occured, please check

Comment: Whether it's the gremlins or something else, you seem to have misquoted your source: $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{O}\,|\,\mathrm{H})$ is the likelihood of $\mathrm{H}$, whereas $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{H}\,|\,\mathrm{O})$ is the posterior probability of $\mathrm{H}$.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected it now.